# Flutter 2: Create Gradient Icon without ShaderMask

Tags: flutter, performance, icons, gradient

I am searching a way to create a Gradient Icon without using `ShaderMask()`.

Why without ShaderMask ?

Because calling `saveLayer()` allocates an offscreen buffer. Drawing content into the offscreen buffer might trigger render target switches that are particularly slow in older GPUs. ([official flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/best-practices))

So here the GradientIcon I have made with the ShaderMask.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GradientIcon extends StatefulWidget {
  final IconData? icon;
  final double? size;
  final Gradient? gradient;

  const GradientIcon({
    @required this.icon,
    @required this.size,
    @required this.gradient,
    Key? key
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GradientIconState createState() => _GradientIconState();
}

class _GradientIconState extends State<GradientIcon> {
  double size = 0;
  static const iconSizeMultiplier = 1.2;

  Shader? shaderFromGradient;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (widget.size != null)
      size = widget.size! * iconSizeMultiplier;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ShaderMask(
      child: Icon(
        widget.icon,
        size: size,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
        return widget.gradient!.createShader(Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, size, size));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

So my question is : Is there a way of rendering Gradient Icon without calling `saveLayer()`, so without calling `ShaderMask()` ?

Comment: is it an issue even when used with `RepaintBoundary`?

Comment: On the official documentation it says "Other widgets that might trigger saveLayer() and are potentially costly:
ShaderMask,
ColorFilter,
Chip—might cause call to saveLayer() if disabledColorAlpha != 0xff,
Text—might cause call to saveLayer() if there’s an overflowShader".
So yes.

Comment: i mean if you tried wrapping everything with `RepaintBoundary` widget - i already know that `saveLayoer` can be expensive

Comment: Well, I have never used it so don't know really how I can paint it

Comment: `return RepaintBoundary(child: ShaderMask(...`

Comment: @pskink thank you so much ! By the way if you know for this one too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69403327/flutter-2-create-gradient-selectabletext-without-shadermask (because here I can make a gradient text with paint but gradient selectable text, I don't know)

Comment: sure, your welcome, how does the other question differ from this one?

Comment: @pskink it differs from the "selectable", here in the solution I proposed, I have used `TextPainter` with `TextSpan` however it is not selectable until we use `SelectableText.rich(` before. However we can't because text is of type `InlineSpan?`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GradientIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final Gradient gradient;
  final double size;

  const GradientIcon(
    this.icon,
    this.gradient,
    {
      this.size = 24,
      Key? key
    }
  ) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RepaintBoundary(
      child: CustomPaint(
        size: Size(size, size),
        painter: _GradientIconPainter(
          icon: icon,
          gradient: gradient,
          iconSize: size
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}

class _GradientIconPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final IconData? icon;
  final Gradient? gradient;
  final double? iconSize;

  _GradientIconPainter({
    Listenable? repaint,
    @required this.icon,
    @required this.gradient,
    @required this.iconSize
  }) : super(repaint: repaint);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final Paint _gradientShaderPaint = Paint()
      ..shader = gradient!.createShader(
          Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height)
      );

    final TextPainter _textPainter = TextPainter(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      text: TextSpan(
        text: String.fromCharCode(icon!.codePoint),
        style: TextStyle(
          foreground: _gradientShaderPaint,
          fontFamily: icon!.fontFamily,
          fontSize: iconSize
        ),
      )
    );
    _textPainter.layout(
      minWidth: 0,
      maxWidth: size.width,
    );

    final xCenter = (size.width - _textPainter.width) / 2;
    final yCenter = (size.height - _textPainter.height) / 2;
    final offset = Offset(xCenter, yCenter);
    _textPainter.paint(canvas, offset);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(_GradientIconPainter oldDelegate) {
    return icon != oldDelegate.icon || gradient != oldDelegate.gradient ||
    iconSize != oldDelegate.iconSize;
  }
}
```

Comment: btw for simple cases (like your) `TextPainter` api can be more handy than `Paragraph` ...

Comment: @pskink thank you for your review, I have updated it with `TextPainter`

Comment: ... and if you have `Size` then instead of verbose `Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height)` just use nice shortcut: `Offset.zero & size` ;-)

Comment: Oh yes smart AND operator !